# Why pop-up not showing in all apps

Tags: android

I updated my samsung phone to latest version but after this update pop-up not working.

For example :

1- Toast not showing in all apps. 
2- Messenger bubble app not showing. 
3- And all apps.

What do you think about the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Android Pie has problems if you want to fire a cascade of Toasts. I came across this "issue" in my latest Application. Maybe you have the same issue with the Messenger Bubble but without any code it is hard to tell what the issue is in your Messanger.

Answer (Toasts): Android Pie - Android Pie overrides the previous one.

Answer (Messenger): Provide some sample-code.

Comment: Can I reset old version ?

Comment: You mean if you can go back to Android Oreo? Yes, there are many tutorials on the internet and on YouTube. Just search for: Downgrade to Android 8